# Matching if/else statement with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently writing a regular expression which will allow me to use a basic conditional if/else system written in JavaScript. (I know there is probably easier ways to do this!)

This is the content I need to work with:

```
{?if language = german}Hallo!{?else}Hello!{?endif}
{?if language = german}{#greeting}{?endif}
```

I have written `/{\?if ([^{}]+)}(.+)(?:{\?else})?(.+)?{\?endif}/g` which unfortunately only matches part of this. I have been using RegExr for testing so far.

My expected output, using the output expression `1: $1\n2: $2\n3: $3\n`, would be:

```
1: language = german
2: Hallo!
3: Hello!

1: language = german
2: {#greeting}
3:
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this instead:

```
1: language = german
2: Hallo!{?else}Hello!
3: 

1: language = german
2: {#greeting}
3:
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm relatively new to writing regular expressions, so I assume there is a way, and I'm just not doing it correctly.

Comment: I agree that there are easier ways to do this!  But, +1 for a good clear question.

Comment: Try using non-greedy quantifiers. Since `else` is optional, the greedy quantifier is going past it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first want to make the `+` operators [**non-greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap). Then instead of making the third capturing group optional, simply place that group inside of the Non-capturing group leaving the Non-capturing group optional.

```
/{\?if ([^{}]+)}(.+?)(?:{\?else}(.+?))?{\?endif}/g
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV5kF7/2)